# How to insert a button in the MapKit annotation

Tags: ios4, mapkit, mkannotation

I am very new to MapKit so forgive me if I do not make sense when I am asking questions. I would like to replicate the default Map application that comes on the iPhone and iPod Touch. There is this feature that I am interested in but can't seem to find it here, google, other iPhone app sites. If you would to run the default Maps application, the annotation title has and image and a button. How do I do both the image and button? What is the name of the method should I call?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are called rightCalloutAccessoryView and leftCalloutAccessoryView.

http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKAnnotationView/leftCalloutAccessoryView

http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKAnnotationView/rightCalloutAccessoryView

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have problems finding my stuff in the documentation. So thats why I ask questions. :)